# Binary Search Fundamentals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I've difficulty in understanding when to use:

while (left < right ) {
}
vs when to use:

while (left <= right ) {
}
Also while setting left and right boundaries sometimes we use:

left = mid
and sometime we use

left = mid + 1;
similarly

right = mid; vs
right = mid - 1;
Is there any fundamental I am missing in knowledge of Binary search ?

Comment: It's easier to talk about if you show your entire implementation.

Comment: What implementation do you refer to? Wiki page contains some BS routines with own peculiarities.

Comment: It all depends. Algorithms do not exist by themselves or for themselves. They are carefully crafted to solve specific problems. Without a specific problem statement one can't know why a specific condition was used. For example, you may assume the target value must exist in the array or not. You may assume there can be duplicates or not. If they can exist, you may want to find the first of them or any one. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

while (left < right ) { }

In this case, the iteration will not stop until the condition is met, which is that if the value in left is less than the value of right, the iteration will be stopped.

while (left <= right ) { }

In this case, the iteration will stop when one of the two conditions is satisfied, the first condition if the value of the left is less than the value of the right and the second condition when the value of the left is equal to the value of the right. If one of the two conditions is met, the iteration will be closed.